# Revoking Certificates for VPN Connection

Tags: security, vpn, certificates

would like to ask what happens when you press on the `clear credentials` options during an established always-on VPN connection.

As I came across a situation where:
The CA certificated was installed on the phone, while the client cert is stored on an SD card and both have been saved as in a working always-on VPN connection. The client cert was on the SD card and when the SD card was removed, the VPN still managed to connect.

If the VPN certificates still remained under the saved connection, isn't it a security concern?

Comment: Usually certificates are imported into the user certificate store. This is the one you can reset by `clear credentials`.